# C# Regex pattern to match keyword

Tags: regex, c#-6.0

Question about regex pattern. I have a string input that I like to match to my array of strings. Input is not constant. For example my test inputs are "test123MakeLunch23" and "testMakeLunch(1)" I have an array of string. Example "MakeLunch" should be match to my test inputs and "DeliverLunch" should be false. I'm having a hard time on getting this work.

```
 string input = "test123MakeLunch23";
 List<string> lstKeywords = new List<string>() { "MakeLunch", "DeliverLunch"};
 foreach (var keyword in lstKeywords)
 {
   // this is not right
   string pattern = $@"^([a-zA-Z0-9{keyword}a-zA-Z0-9)$";

   // on MakeLunch should return true only
   bool ismatch = Regex.IsMatch(input,pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 }
```

And can you add some explanation to the solution. Thank you.

Comment: I think not the same

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? What the regex pattern should search?

Comment: Regex pattern would check if my input and my keyword match. In my example "MakeLunch" should be true. And "DeliverLunch" is false.

Comment: Please try to generalize your questions, i.e. how do I check if a string contains a word, and use the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to test whether keyword exists in your input string. You don't need Regex for this:

```
string input = "test123MakeLunch23";
string keyword = "MakeLunch";
bool is_match = input.IndexOf(keyword) > -1;
```

Comment: Change your input to "MakeLunch23" it will fail

Comment: My bad for forgetting indexOf. Thanks